# cordova requirements issue with Android target: "android-24

Tags: android, cordova

While installing requirements for cordova in ubuntu... i am facing the target android issue:

> Android target: not installed
>
> Please install [Android target: "android-24][1]  #target".
>
> Hint: Open the SDK manager by running:
>   /home/hemanth/android-studio/tools/android

You will require:

1. "SDK Platform" for android-24 #target
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)

Gradle: installed

Requirements check results for browser:

> Check failed for browser due to Failed to check requirements for
>   browser platform. check_reqs module is missing for platform. Skipping
>   it... Error: Some of requirements check failed

Even I have installed api 24 still I am getting same error

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwvns.png*

how to correct this target android error?

Comment: `Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /home/hemanth/android-studio/tools/android` and so on doesn't help you?

Comment: nope.... i tried that but its just showing installed pkgs (sdk-tools, platform-tools, apis..)avail pkgs even i installed that api-24 api-25 but still same error.. @Divers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it..its just installation issue...api-24 version supported by cordova but have to install all APIs ..before doing click on start new project in android-studio

```
android-studio home page ->settings -> sdk manager -> Select APIS to download
```

now no issue with target android error

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Mrs.png "cordova requirements result"

Answer (score 1):

As per their documentation only API Version `23` and below are supported (as of `2017-01-11`. Down to version `10` or version `14` of the android API depending on your version of Cordova): http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html

---

## Requirements and Support

Cordova for Android requires the Android SDK which can be installed on OS X, Linux or Windows. See the Android SDK's System Requirements. Cordova's latest Android package supports up to Android API-Level 28¹. The supported Android API-Levels for the past few cordova-android releases can be found in this table:

```
cordova-android      Supported Android      Equivalent Android
Version              API-Levels             Version
8.X.X                19 - 28                4.4 - 9.0.0
7.X.X                19 - 27                4.4 - 8.1
6.X.X                16 - 26                4.1 - 8.0.0
5.X.X                14 - 23                4.0 - 6.0.1
4.1.X                14 - 22                4.0 - 5.1
4.0.X                10 - 22                2.3.3 - 5.1
3.7.X                10 - 21                2.3.3 - 5.0.2
```

Please note that the versions listed here are for Cordova's Android package, cordova-android, and not for the Cordova CLI. To determine what version of Cordova's Android package is installed in your Cordova project, run the command `cordova platform ls` in the directory that holds your project.

As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by Cordova as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution dashboard.

**¹NOTE: This has been updated as of 2020-04-18 to update information in the table above. The wording of the post is being retained as answered so as to speak to the original question as asked.  Future readers are advised that they should consult the source link to confirm version compatibility.**

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an old version of the SDK, the `android` cmd is deprecated.  Instead try this 1st: `avdmanager list target`

I'm assuming it won't return anything so then run this: `sdkmanager --list`
The 1st thing it spits out is what you have installed followed by a list of available packages.  Assuming you don't have any `platforms` installed, look in the list of available packages for `platforms;android-XX` where XX is the version you wish to target (it should match your platform-tools version)

Then run: `sdkmanager "platforms;android-XX"`

Now when you run `avdmanager list target` you should see the API version you just installed and your app should build.